# OpenGL - Getting The Display Color Bits

Tags: opengl, screenshot, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm looking at the LWJGL wiki for taking a screenshot (found [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Taking_Screen_Shots)) and I noticed the comment *Assuming a 32-bit display with a byte each for red, green, blue, and alpha.* in this code:

```
GL11.glReadBuffer(GL11.GL_FRONT);
int width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height= Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
int bpp = 4; // Assuming a 32-bit display with a byte each for red, green,
//blue, and alpha.
ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * bpp);
GL11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
```

How would I change the var *bpp* based off of the current system?

Comment: What do you mean by 'current system'?

Comment: OpenGL should not be abused for creating screenshots of the system display. You can use it to store the contents of a OpenGL drawable's contents, but the sometimes found technique of creating a fullscreen, bottom layer window to grab a screenshot is highly unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still looking for an answer:

You can get the bytes per pixel of the current display mode by getting it from LWJGL's Display class. It would look something like this:

```
int bpp = Display.getDisplayMode().getBitsPerPixel()/4
```